# How can we make this qubit heatmap in Vega spec

Tags: javascript, visualization, altair, vega-lite, vega

I want to create this type of hexagonal heatmap, but can't seem to find this anywhere.

Heat map
[image: Heat map]

I tried to make it but no luck.

here's my vega spec :

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega/v5.json",
  "width": 500,
  "height": 300,
  "padding": {"left": 10, "top": 10, "right": 10, "bottom": 10},

  "signals": [
    {
      "name": "hexRadius",
      "value": 35
    },
    {
      "name": "hexWidth",
      "update": "sqrt(0) * hexRadius"
    },
    {
      "name": "hexHeight",
      "update": "0 * hexRadius"
    }
  ],

  "data": [
    {
      "name": "heatmapData",
      "values": [
        {"row": 1, "column": 1, "metric": 0.01},
        {"row": 2, "column": 1, "metric": 0.02},
        {"row": 3, "column": 1, "metric": 0.03},
        {"row": 1, "column": 2, "metric": 0.04},
        {"row": 2, "column": 2, "metric": 0.05},
        {"row": 3, "column": 2, "metric": 0.06},
        {"row": 1, "column": 3, "metric": 0.07},
        {"row": 2, "column": 3, "metric": 0.08},
        {"row": 3, "column": 3, "metric": 0.09}
      ]
    }
  ],

  "scales": [
    {
      "name": "x",
      "type": "point",
      "domain": {"data": "heatmapData", "field": "column"},
      "range": "width",
      "padding": 0.5
    },
    {
      "name": "y",
      "type": "point",
      "domain": {"data": "heatmapData", "field": "row"},
      "range": "height",
      "padding": 1
    },
    {
      "name": "color",
      "type": "linear",
      "domain": [0.01, 0.09],
      "range": {"scheme": "purples"}
    }
  ],

  "axes": [
    {
      "orient": "left",
      "scale": "y",
      "title": "Row",
      "tickCount": 3
    },
    {
      "orient": "bottom",
      "scale": "x",
      "title": "Column",
      "tickCount": 3
    }
  ],

  "marks": [
    {
      "type": "path",
      "from": {"data": "heatmapData"},
      "encode": {
        "enter": {
          "path": {
            "signal": "'M' + (0) + ',' + (-hexRadius) + ' L' + (hexRadius * sin(60)) + ',' + (-hexRadius/2) + ' L' + (hexRadius * sin(60)) + ',' + (hexRadius/2) + ' L' + (0) + ',' + (hexRadius) + ' L' + (-hexRadius * sin(60)) + ',' + (hexRadius/2) + ' L' + (-hexRadius * sin(60)) + ',' + (-hexRadius/2) + ' Z'"
          },
          "x": {
            "scale": "x",
            "field": "column",
            "offset": {"signal": "datum.column % 2 === 0 ? hexWidth / 2 : 0"}
          },
          "y": {
            "scale": "y",
            "field": "row",
            "offset": {"signal": "datum.row % 2 === 0 ? hexHeight / 2 : 0"}
          },
          "fill": {"scale": "color", "field": "metric"},
          "stroke": {"value": "white"},
          "strokeWidth": {"value": 1}
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "text",
      "from": {"data": "heatmapData"},
      "encode": {
        "enter": {
          "x": {
            "scale": "x",
            "field": "column",
            "offset": {"signal": "datum.column % 2 === 0 ? hexWidth / 2 : 0"}
          },
          "y": {
            "scale": "y",
            "field": "row",
            "offset": {"signal": "datum.row % 2 === 0 ? hexHeight / 2 : 0"}
          },
          "text": {"field": "metric"},
          "align": {"value": "center"},
          "baseline": {"value": "middle"},
          "fill": {"value": "black"}
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: You would need to create your own svg shapes similar to this example to create a map like that https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/hexbins.html. Either create a horizontal and vertical shape and plot half of the data with each, or  set the angle/rotation according for the horizontal vertical ones

Answer (score 1):

As Joel suggested, you could create a spec using images, 2 layers and filter each layer accordingly. Here is a very basic spec using 2 hexagon shapes just to demonstrate what's possible.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "description": "A scatterplot showing horsepower and miles per gallons for various cars.",
  "width": 500,
  "height": 500,
  "data": {"url": "data/cars.json"},
  "layer": [
    {
      "transform": [{"filter": "datum.Horsepower <= 150"}],
      "mark": {
        "type": "image",
        "url": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/84/Truncated_triangle.svg/80px-Truncated_triangle.svg.png",
        "width": 30,
        "height": 30
      },
      "encoding": {
        "x": {"field": "Horsepower", "type": "quantitative"},
        "y": {"field": "Miles_per_Gallon", "type": "quantitative"}
      }
    },
    {
      "transform": [{"filter": "datum.Horsepower > 150"}],
      "mark": {
        "type": "image",
        "url": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/38/Regular_polygon_6_annotated.svg/80px-Regular_polygon_6_annotated.svg.png",
        "width": 30,
        "height": 30
      },
      "encoding": {
        "x": {"field": "Horsepower", "type": "quantitative"},
        "y": {"field": "Miles_per_Gallon", "type": "quantitative"}
      }
    }
  ],
  "config": {}
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to use text marks. Using unicode characters can be a very fast and effective way of displaying special characters like stars, hexagons etc. In the example below I am using a a pointy and flat hexagon in 2 layers.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "description": "A scatterplot showing horsepower and miles per gallons for various cars.",
  "width": 500,
  "height": 500,
  "data": {"url": "data/cars.json"},
  "transform": [
    {"filter": "datum.Horsepower > 120 & datum.Horsepower < 170"},
    {"filter": "datum.Miles_per_Gallon < 20"}
  ],
  "encoding": {
    "x": {
      "field": "Horsepower",
      "type": "quantitative",
      "scale": {"zero": false, "nice": true}
    },
    "y": {
      "field": "Miles_per_Gallon",
      "type": "quantitative",
      "scale": {"zero": false, "nice": true}
    }
  },
  "layer": [
    {
      "transform": [
        {"filter": "datum.Horsepower > 150 & datum.Horsepower < 170"}
      ],
      "mark": {"type": "text", "text": "⬢", "size": 40, "color": "purple"}
    },
    {
      "transform": [
        {"filter": "datum.Horsepower > 120 & datum.Horsepower < 150"}
      ],
      "mark": {"type": "text", "text": "⬣", "size": 40, "color": "blue"}
    }
  ],
  "config": {}
}
```

[image]